# Is it allowed to wear inner gloves while batting in cricket?

Tags: rules, cricket, equipment, history

We can see the wicket keepers always wearing inner gloves on field.

[image]

- Is it permitted for a batsman to wear inner gloves while batting in
  cricket?
- Is there any batsman wear them in international cricket history?

Comment: I saw Nasser Hossain (of England) wearing inner Gloves several times. I don't have a pictorial proof right now, that's why I am making it a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @Aamir, pictorial proof found :-)

Comment: @SportsFan - Nice *About Me* image :-). Hope you don't mind for [the question](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/q/452/540) I have posted on Meta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Appendix-d](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/appendix-d/)

> For a batsman, items permitted are a protective helmet, external leg guards (batting pads), **batting gloves** and, if visible, forearm guards.

So batting gloves are permitted (as everyone know). Now inner gloves are not necessary to wear. But some batsmen and wicket keepers wear it for absorb the sweat and more grip.

From [this post](http://www.procricketgear.com/importance-of-batting-gloves-and-wicket-keeping-gloves.php):

> Many batsmen and wicket keepers opt wearing an extra thin pair of gloves called inners beneath their batting or wicket keeping gloves. This is primarily intended to absorb the sweat and perspiration. Many international cricket stars wear inners as batsmen find them helpful in gripping the bat more firmly and wicket keepers find inners useful for neatly collecting the ball behind the stumps.

So it is fully permitted to wear inner gloves for batsmen too. You can also search for such equipment on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=batting%20inner%20gloves&oq=batting%20inner%20gloves&gs_l=serp.3...1944458.1946487.2.1947096.12.9.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.27.serp..22.5.1619.dNtxpudsjgc&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.53077864,d.bmk,pv.xjs.s.en_US.b5VD5atLOcw.O&biw=1280&bih=909&dpr=1).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is allowed to wear inner gloves and there are some players(like Nasir Hussain, Alec Stewart and Rahul Dravid) having the habit of wearing them.

**See the below image,**

[image]

**It couldn't be his outer glove, since they are placed in his helmet.**

[image]

Comment: Ohh I couldn't find images of players with inner gloves. +1 for your research.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is allowed for a player to wear the inner gloves, however there is no restriction in terms of wearing inner gloves while batting,wicket keeping, but the fielding team(except wicket keeper ) is not allowed to wear the inner gloves.

Comment: Where is that mentioned, that the field team is not allowed to wear inner gloves?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra It's implicit in the fact that they are not allowed to wear _any_ gloves (inner or otherwise).

Comment: @Spinner so this answer is wrong?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra No, it's correct. The batsmen and the wicketkeeper may wear gloves (no distinction is made between outer batting/keeping gloves and inner gloves); all other players may not.